# Is the behaviour undefined when adding to a fixed length array pointer so that there is an overflow?

Tags: c

Take a look at the following code, taken from an older version of ffmpeg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo
{
    int16_t (*ac_val_base)[16];
    int16_t (*ac_val[3])[16];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct foo bar;
    int16_t *ac_val, *ac_val1;

    bar.ac_val_base = malloc(4639 * 16 * sizeof(int16_t));
    bar.ac_val[0] = bar.ac_val_base + 66;

    ac_val = bar.ac_val[0][0] + 3780 * 16;
    ac_val1 = ac_val;
    
    printf("Result: %d\n", (int) (((char *) ac_val1) - ((char *) bar.ac_val[0][0])));

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this with established compilers like gcc or Visual C, the result is 120960. This makes sense to me because I'm adding `3780 * 16` to an `int16_t` array pointer so I'd expect the resulting pointer to be 120960 bytes above the source pointer.

When compiling the code using vbcc, however, the result is -8000 because the compiler performs some optimizations. The author of the vbcc compiler is convinced that the optimization is covered by 6.5.6/8 of the C99 standard which says that the behaviour is undefined in that case, quote:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the
> same array object, or one past the last element of the array object,
> the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior
> is undefined.

So is the code above really relying on undefined behaviour? I'm a bit skeptical because the code works on all compilers except vbcc.

Comment: I think the standard is clear. Yes it is undefined behaviour. The fact that compillers produce something that makes sense doesn't make it defined and you can't rely on in. It may change with the next version or another optimization level

Comment: *I'd expect the resulting pointer to be 120960 bytes above the source pointer.*  And that's clearly well beyond "one past the last element of the array object"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the type of the expression `bar.ac_val[0][0]` is "array of 16 `int16_t`".  Although this array object is located within a larger malloc block, and the expression evaluates to a pointer within the block, the pointer has *provenance* from an array.

A pointer obtained from an array expression, where the array dimension is N, can be displaced by at most N (one byte past the end of the array), while staying within defined behavior.  (If displaced all the way to N, the pointer must not be dereferenced.)

A simpler example is something like:

```
struct obj {
  int arr[32];
  int other_member;
};
```

Suppose you have a `malloc`-ed pointer to this, but use `ptr->arr[32]` to access `other_member`, this is not well-defined, even though everything is in the `malloc`-ed object.

One possible optimization the compiler can perform is to use some addressing mode which only works for that size of array. Say that `ptr->arr[i]` translates to some instruction which has a five-bit field to encode a scaled displacement value from 0 to 31. The compiler is free to ignore that the displacement [32] cannot fit into that instruction, and just truncate it to the lowest five bits, which are zero, effectively changing the meaning to `ptr->arr[0]`.

Alternatively, the rules can enable useful diagnostic tools. The compiler may be able to warn you at compile time that there is an array overrun, and because it's undefined behavior, it can fail the translation, while remaining conforming.   There can be tooling whereby the code is compiled in such a way that you get detailed array bound checking at run time (not just checking for overrun of the `malloc`-ed block). Accessing past the end of the array can be an accident, resulting in a hard-to-find bug, particularly if the access doesn't go past the allocation.

Comment: But according to the quote from the C99 standard in my OP accessing `ptr->arr[32]` to access `other_member` is defined behaviour because it is just one past the array size. AFAIU undefined behaviour would start at `ptr->arr[33]` because 33 is more than one past the array size or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Andreas Ah, that is false. In C, you may calculate a pointer which is one element past the end of an array-like object. The ability to do this is a requirement and is therefore well-defined.  However, it is not well defined to dereference such a pointer.

Comment: Not every pointer which is valid may be dereferenced.   A null pointer is valid, but may not be deferenced.   A pointer past the end of an array is the same.  A valid pointer that may not be used to access anything is useful. You can compare a null pointer against a null constant to determine whether it is null, as a useful indication of something like "we don't currently have an object in this variable". Likewise, a pointer past the end of an array is useful for comparison and for arithmetic.   You can use it it in a loop termination test, and such.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
ac_val = bar.ac_val[0][0] + 3780 * 16;
```

`bar.ac_val[0][0]` is `int16_t[16]`, so that adding anything other than values in range [0, 16) to it results in undefined behaviour.

The reason for the undefined behaviour is segmented memory model (as opposed to modern flat/linear memory model) which C is still compatible with, when pointer values are composed of segment descriptor and byte offset within the segment. In such a model, distinct arrays may reside in different segments. Segment descriptor units are not byte offsets, so that subtracting segment descriptor values doesn't produce distance in bytes. The difference between pointers to different arrays residing in different segments ends up subtracting segment descriptors resulting in undefined behaviour.

Your particular array is allocated using `malloc`. It cannot possibly span multiple memory segments. As long as your pointers, including expression temporaries, don't point outside this heap allocated array, these pointers are valid and well-defined.

It is the array element type `int16_t[16]` and indexing outside its bounds what causes the undefined behaviour. This array element type is essentially a red herring for a C compiler.

If you switch your array element type to plain `int16_t` and convert your 2d array indexes into 1d, e.g. `[row][column]` to `[row * n_columns + column]`, this problem ceases to exist.

---

You can also side-step the undefined behaviour arising from pointer arithmetic with integer arithmetic:

```
uintptr_t ac_val = (uintptr_t)bar.ac_val[0][0] + 3780 * 16 * sizeof(int16_t);
printf("Result: %zu\n", (size_t) ((ac_val - ((uintptr_t) bar.ac_val[0][0])));
```

This relies on the facts that:

- Converting a pointer to `uintptr_t` and back is well-defined.
- Unsigned integer addition and subtraction is well-defined.

Comment: You would need to do something similar (I guess) on this line: `ac_val = bar.ac_val[0][0] + 3780 * 16;`. At least, that's the line where clang-cl gives a warning: *the pointer incremented by 60480 refers past the end of the array (that contains 16 elements) [-Warray-bounds-pointer-arithmetic]*

Comment: *You can side-step the undefined behaviour arising from pointer arithmetic*  I'm not so sure about that.  When the result is assigned to the `ac_val` in your example, it remains a `uintptr_t` without invoking UB.  **But**, if it gets assigned into the `int16_t (*ac_val[3])[16];` of `struct foo`, it's converted back to a pointer - a pointer that has its derivation outside the bounds of "elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object".

Comment: @AndrewHenle The integer arithmetic results in valid pointer, should you wish to obtain one, as long as it points within the array allocated by `malloc`. No beyond-bounds indexing of `int16_t[16]` is involved here, which is the root cause of undefined behaviour here.